# How to create a stacked bar waterfall chart in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing around with the D3 stacked bar implementation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981299/d3-stacked-chart-with-array-or-json-data) and expanding it into a [waterfall chart](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/07/25/waterfall-chart-in-excel/) with having the bars consisting of stacked bars instead of just a single category bar.

This image here shows what I ultimately try to get:
[Waterfall Chart with stacked bars image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efhsQ.png)
It can be done by Excel according to this [link](https://upslide.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202485996-Excel-Create-a-Stacked-Waterfall-chart) and in Tableau [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/249471).

It has a total calculation of each period (2012, 2013 etc) and every bar consists of two categories (smartphones and laptops) in their respective color. The waterfall consists of the category `new`and `used` as additions and `returned` as subtractions. One flow can be described as follows:
`2012 (laptop + smartphone) + laptops_new + smartphone_new + laptop_used + smartphone_used - (laptop_returned + smartphone_returned) equals 2013 (laptop + smartphone)`

To make the bars between two periods appear floating above the ground, one must compile a white coloured bar which has the same height as the bar just before. This is being documented in D3 [here](http://bl.ocks.org/rsloan/7123450) but only with simple bars and not stacked ones.

The logic of such a floating waterfall chart and of a stacked bar chart has been shown in D3. However I struggle with the combination of these two together in one chart.

I understand that with `d.total` the total count of the stacked bars of a category is being calculated.

```
 ....
data.forEach(function(d) {
 var y0 = 0;
 d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0:   
 y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
 // Total of stack calculated
 d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
});
 ....
```

For creating the waterfall part I may need to adopt some logic from here

```
....
data.forEach(function(d) {
//first calculate the starting height for each category
total = 0
totals = {}
for (var i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
  if (i == 3) {
    total = total - +d[categories[i]];
    totals[categories[i]] = total;
  }
  else {
    totals[categories[i]] = total;
    total += +d[categories[i]];
  }
}
//then map category name, value, and starting height to each observation
d.formatted = categories.map(function(category) {
  return {
    name: category,
    value: +d[category],
    baseHeight: +totals[category]
  };
});
});
....
```

How can I implement this waterfall logic into the stacked bar chart such that I can achieve something which looks like the stacked bar waterfall chart in the image?

Comment: Do you have an example of the type of chart you are trying to create?

Comment: Thanks. I uploaded an image on how it should look like and updated the question above with more details. I also included a link to such a chart with excel.

Even with extensive research I did not found a D3 implementation of a waterfall chart.

Comment: Here is another description in the tableau community: https://community.tableau.com/thread/249471